# How do I delete the contents within a directory without removing the directory itself? Command shell or Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

```
cd C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Group Policy\History
>del *
```

This is what I have tired to use to delete the contents in the History folder. While trying to retain the History directory

There are 6 files I would like to delete but the file names are excessively long. 
I need to do it repeatedly && the file names change.

Eventually I will turn this into a script.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `cmd / batch` solution

```
pushd "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Group Policy\History" && ( rmdir . /s /q 2>nul & popd )
```

Just change the current active directory to the indicated one (`pushd`) and if this command did not fail (`&&` conditional execution operator) then remove the current folder and all its contents (`rd`) and return to the previous active directory (`popd`)

Note that the `rd` command will not be able to remove the current active directory (the reason to first change to it) and the error redirection to `nul` stream to avoid showing the fail on trying to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Command shell:

PROMPT> cd C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Group Policy\History
PROMPT> del *.*   /s  /q

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell:

```
Remove-Item 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Group Policy\History\*' -Recurse -Force
```

In CMD:

```
del /q "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Group Policy\History\*"
for /d %d in ("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Group Policy\History\*") do @rmdir /s /q "%~fd"
```

`del /s /q` does not suffice in CMD because it deletes only files, not folders.

Answer (score 0):

Directories without a `.` character will not be deleted using `*.*`. Use `*` instead. You might need to Run as Administrator.

When you are confident that the correct items will be deleted, remove the `WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

```
Remove-Item -Path "$Env:ProgramData\Microsoft\Group Policy\History\*" -Recurse -WhatIf
```